# Updating excel file using Windows Forms off of a sub-thread; Returns rows affected but file doesn't update

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, excel

I am writing a Window Forms application (that also has a console attached to it for debugging threads) that allows me to choose an excel file and perform operations on said file. This file contains transaction information such as [Date], [Store], [Department] and more.

The entire goal of this project is to separate out each job into threads. There are four main jobs.

1:) Pulling the next unaffected excel file row and updating it.

2:) Looking that excel transaction up in the data base and adding the resulting object into a list in memory.

3:) Processing the transactions that were pulled from the data base.

4:) Updating the excel file with notes after processing.

Every one of these four jobs will have a thread except for 3. That will be done off of the main thread. I wait for the threads to join back up before ending the session. So if _Processing = false it will still wait for all updates to finish saving before moving on.

My main method first runs a clean up job to set any transactions that were pulled into memory but not processed. This is a simple method, there are no threads and it runs just one command. 
('UPDATE [MissingTransactions$] SET Notes = '' WHERE Notes = 'Pulled'). This is ran because when I pull a transaction I set Notes = 'Pulled', if the job fails I want these set back to empty strings.

The issue comes into play when I try to update the file to set Notes = 'Pulled' from a sub-thread off of the main thread. This is my update method.

Here is how I build out my commands; I run two commands in this one method, one to pull and one to update the transaction I pulled.

```
    private void GetNextExcelTransaction(ref List<ITransaction> iExcelList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pulling Excel Transaction");
        OleDbCommand lCommand = new OleDbCommand(Commands.Commands.SelectNextAvailableTransaction);
        DataTable lNextTransaction = _DataAccess.ExecuteQueryCommand(lCommand, Commands.Commands.SelectNextAvailableTransaction, 0);
        ITransaction aNextTransaction = AssignRowToTransaction(lNextTransaction);

        iExcelList.Add(aNextTransaction);
        Console.WriteLine("Excel transacion added to list");

        OleDbCommand lUpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("UPDATE [MissingTransactions$] SET Notes = 'Pulled' WHERE DSDRTNormalized = '{0}';", aNextTransaction.DSDRT));
        _DataAccess.ExecuteNonQueryCommand(lUpdateCommand);
        Console.WriteLine("Set transaction to pulled");
    }

    public void ExecuteNonQueryCommand(OleDbCommand iCommand)
    {
        if (iCommand == new OleDbCommand() || iCommand == null) { throw new InvalidDataException("iCommand passed was null"); }
        int lRowsAffected = 0;
        try
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine("Updating Excel File using command {0}", iCommand.CommandText);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            using (OleDbConnection lConnection = new OleDbConnection(Commands.Commands._ConnectionString))
            {
                iCommand.Connection = lConnection;
                lConnection.Open();
                using (iCommand)
                {
                    lRowsAffected = iCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                lConnection.Close();
                lConnection.Dispose();

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Excel File Update Complete, {0} Row affected using command {1}", lRowsAffected, iCommand.CommandText);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception lException)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Update Failed");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }
```

I had a check for rows affected but it was bypassed because my ExecuteNonQueryCommand actually returns 1 row affected but the excel file was unchanged.

Here is my Connection String;

```
    _ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + iFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
```

If I add IMEX 1 or 2 to the extended properties in my connection string I get an exception when executing commands. "Operation must use an updateable query." but I have the necessary permissions on the file and the folder it is in to make changes to it.

If you need an Edit for more code or a better explanation just let me know.

Comment: This is a good quality question and I wonder why it didn't get the attention it deserves.

Comment: Thank You! I am not sure why either.

Comment: Are you still waiting for a response? Because now is the time for me to check the problem :)

Comment: Yes. I am still wondering what is going on. lol

Comment: I should close this out I guess. The issue was there was way to much data connectivity to the excel file (pulls, and updates) which caused the file to become un-responsive but not throw any exceptions.

Comment: I'm glad it's resolved, but why close? Post that as an answer. It could be helpful for someone else :)